# What is exactly those weights parameters of Iris Flowers, considering a linear regression model?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

```
X.shape >>> (120, 4)
Y.shape >>> (120,)

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(x_train,y_train)

model.coef_ >>> 
array([[-0.4345272 ,  0.81754718, -2.35369834, -0.97519974],
       [ 0.61879329, -0.42290961, -0.204655  , -0.82624438],
       [-0.18426609, -0.39463757,  2.55835334,  1.80144412]])
```

Since this problem has 4 variables (features), I thought this would be the equation: $ŷ_1=β_0+β_1X_1+β_2X_2+β_3X_3+β_4X_4$

However, as model.coef_ shows, I have 12 parameters instead: 
$β_1,...,β_{12}$

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is correct in the case that you are performing binary classification, i.e. when you have just two classes. The iris dataset, however, has three classes and because of this `scikit-learn` will use three equations, one for each class. [As the documentation mentions](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), the coefficients array will therefore be of shape `(n_classes, n_features)`. This is why `model.coef_` returns an array of shape `(3, 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

Binary Logistic Regression has a simple form

$$
y = \frac{1}{1+e^{-Xw}}
$$

where $X$ is your $objects \times features$ matrix and $w$ is a learnt vector of model weights. Now, recall sizes of all vectors (for simplicity I omit sigmoid activation, since it does not affect matrices sizes):

$$
y_{n \times 1} = X_{n \times m} w_{m \times 1}
$$

the resulting vector $y$ (after sigmoid activation) contains numbers between 0 and 1, interpreted as probability of an objects being of class "1" (the closer the number to 1 the higher the probability).

Now, if you want to predict the probability of an object to be of one of 3 classes (as in Iris dataset), your vector $w$ should be a matrix $W$:

$$
y_{n \times c} = X_{n \times m} w_{m \times c}
$$

Now, every $y_i$ will contain $c$ numbers between 0 and 1 (after applying some nonlinearity, e.g. sigmoid again) - likelihoods of the $i$'th object being of $c$'th class.

Comment: Thanks for explaining in detail. Just a correction, Iris dataset has three classes to be predicted (Setosa, Versicolor and Virginica), not four. But each $X_i$ has four attributes (sepal: length, width and petal: length; width).

Comment: Right, 3 classes, fixed